# Getting username from Telegram user in inline query

Tags: python-2.7, inline, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have this certain piece of code to perform an inline query in Telegram:

```
def inlinequery(bot, update):
    """Handle the inline query."""
    query = update.inline_query.query
    start_user=update['from']['username']
    start_user=start_user.encode('utf-8')
```

I need to get the username of the user that performs the inline query, into the variable 'start_user'. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `from` object with the `username` is stored in the `inline_query` object.

You should find it with `update.inline_query.from.username`

Note that there might be users without a username, as it is not mandatory to have one.